# Is there a way to make shotgun output requests?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, shotgun

When I run `sinatra` app without `shotgun`, it tells about every request being done:

```
$ ruby app.rb
[2014-03-21 16:56:03] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2014-03-21 16:56:03] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2013-06-27) [x86_64-linux]
== Sinatra/1.4.4 has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from WEBrick
[2014-03-21 16:56:03] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=27957 port=4567
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Mar/2014 16:56:07] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 12 0.0019
localhost - - [21/Mar/2014:16:56:07 EET] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 12
- -> /
```

`shotgun` doesn't do this:

```
$ shotgun -p 4567 app.rb
== Shotgun/WEBrick on http://127.0.0.1:4567/
[2014-03-21 16:58:05] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2014-03-21 16:58:05] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2013-06-27) [x86_64-linux]
[2014-03-21 16:58:05] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=28322 port=4567
```

Is there a way to make `shotgun` work the same way?